# Cesium: How can I determine if two polygons overlap?

Tags: cesiumjs

I have a [sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

What I am trying to do is determine whether two polygons overlap. However, I only care if they overlap if all of the points from the polygons could be visible.

To solve this problem, my plan is to:

1. project the points from the polygons to the window
2. using the projected polygons, perform an easy 2D polygon intersection
3. win

Projecting points from the polygons is easy using `Cesium.SceneTransforms.wgs84ToWindowCoordinates`.

The problem I am having is I am not sure how to determine whether or not a point in a polygon is facing away from the window. How can I do that?

Edit:

One idea I had was the following:

```
function testPolygon() {
  source.entities.values.forEach( (entity) => {
    const name = entity.properties.name?.getValue();
    const positions = entity.polygon.hierarchy.valueOf().positions;
    const camera = viewer.camera;
    const cameraDirection = camera.direction;
    const cameraFrustum = camera.frustum;
    const cameraNearDistance = cameraFrustum.near;
    const nearPlane = new Cesium.Plane( cameraDirection, cameraNearDistance )
    const origin = new Cesium.Cartesian3()
    
    positions.forEach( (position) => {
      const windowCoordinate = Cesium.SceneTransforms.wgs84ToWindowCoordinates(viewer.scene, position);
      
      console.log( "position", position );
      const positionRay = new Cesium.Ray( origin, position )
      
      const intersection = Cesium.IntersectionTests.rayPlane( positionRay, nearPlane )
    })
  });
}
```

The idea here is to construct the near plane from the camera, create a ray from the globe origin ( (0,0,0)? ), and then do an intersection test.

However, it is not working. But, I am not sure why. I am missing something fundamental, but I am not sure what that is yet.

Comment: Instead of projecting them onto a window, try converting these coordinates to Cesium "Cartographic" space, and getting the lat & lon values for each point.  Then you can do polygon intersection by treating longitude as X and latitude as Y in a 2D space. This won't account for Earth curvature (lines between verts will not be great arcs), so the polygons will need to be smaller and not span significant portions of the globe.  But it would be better than window coordinates.